# Foursquare checkins api - trying to get checkins between dates

Tags: api, foursquare, checkin, date-range

I'm using the api @ api.foursquare.com/v2/users/USER_ID/checkins referenced here developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins
I am creating the request using vb.net but that's probably irrelevant. The issue I am having is that the response I receive seems to ignore the beforeTimeStamp value.

For example I have created a request url of this; (oauth_token masked – but is correct and works)
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=####&v=20120214&limit=250&offset=0&afterTimestamp=1332720000&beforeTimestamp=1333238400
1332720000 is the Epoch date 26-03-2012 and 1333238400 is 01-04-2012
I would expect this to return all the checkins between those dates. However it always returns all checkins up to the most recent one, i.e. today 11/04/2012. I spent last night searching for answers to this and I am no further forward.

I could go ahead and write a paging method to move around the history log until I have just the ones I need. This would create multiple requests though.
I even wrote a simple function to strip out checkins that were out of range once I had the objects back. However this seems wasteful, especially as the application I am writing has the potential to go back years in a users history. This would mean returning way more data than required, creating an unneccesary overhead.
After all the searching I was just about resigned to doing one of the 2 workarounds above when I stumbled on the Foursquare API console at https://apigee.com/
If you have read this far, this is the main thrust of this question (unless anyone knows what I am doing wrong…)
If I create a request using the apigee.com interface with the settings above, the response body only contains the checkins I need, i.e. the ones between the specified dates! If I use my app, it returns them all!
My URL  /v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=####&v=20120214&limit=250&offset=0&afterTimestamp=1332720000&beforeTimestamp=1333238400
Apigee’s URL (in the request box after execution)
/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=####&v=20120214&limit=250&offset=0&afterTimestamp=1332720000&beforeTimeStamp=1333238400

Spot the difference? Neither can I! Anyone have any ideas?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a typo in your URL. `beforeTimeStamp` should be `beforeTimestamp`. That's why your second URL is not working. It further seems you mixed up Apigee's URL and your URL in your post.

Retrieving yesterday's checkins works for me as expected:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/self/checkins?oauth_token=###&v=20120321&afterTimestamp=1334120400&beforeTimestamp=1334206799

Also no problem with the API version from 20120214. Also your URLs are working for me.

Comment: Thank-you so much! Obviously I now feel stupid, but I honestly just didn't see that! I am just glad there was an answer... I probably just stared and stared at this way too long. I can confirm it is now working perfectly. Once again, many thanks for taking the time to point out my mistake, it's really appreciated.